# Interrupt table modification

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, interrupt

I'm writing my own operating system and need to know how to modify the interrupt table so that certain ones (print string, etc.) are redirected to the command prompt application, similar to how DOS did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, I've only done this in DOS in what now feels like another life, but - if I recall correctly - all we did was disable interrupts, write a new pointer to the desired entry in the interrupt table (starting at address 0:0), and then re-enable interrupts.

Comment: How wide are the pointers? And what is their structure

Comment: In real mode, the interrupt entries are 4-byte values (segment, offset pairs).

Comment: Just for completeness : the interrupt vector table (as called by the Intel manuals) starts at address 0 by default, but that location can be changed by the `LIDT` instruction. You should note that this instruction is not available on the original 8086, though - but this shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: The os runs in protected mode... What is the structure of that?

Comment: I don't know - I've never worked directly with the interrupt table in protected mode. I suggest you post another question specifying protected mode since you've flagged this one as answered.

Comment: Protected mode makes things much, much more complicated. While the IVT in real mode is simply an array of pointers, the protected mode uses an IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table), which is a table of Interrupt Gates - structures containing more info than just the pointer to an interrupt handler. Read all about it in chapter 6 of "System Programming".